# Can I search for more than just the top 1000 results using Google's Patent Search Engine?

Tags: google

on Google's support page for patent searches (see here: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7049588?hl=en) it says that: "You can download up to the top 1000 results by clicking "Download (CSV)". This may take a few seconds to generate. Fewer than 1000 results may be returned." I want to see more than 1,000 of the results. Is there anyway to do that -- perhaps using a different search engine?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/). It allows download of either 1000 or 10,000 patents via their "Collections" feature. A found a [blog post that goes through it step-by-step](https://www.pauloldham.net/lens/). They have two alternate formats to .csv.

Comment: The Lens also finds more relevant patents than Google Patents based on my experience. You inadvertently spelled “csv” as “cvs”.

Comment: thanks for spotting yet another of my typos.